# Java file write in while loop

Tags: java

I wrote this small phone book program to take 3 user inputted fields and write them to a text file. You will put in a phone number, address, and name. I have most of it encased inside of a while loop. The user is asked for the three inputs and the it is written to a txt file. However lets say you input three values (1 person) then you add another persons information, the program only writes the last person inputted.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class phoneBookMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner
        Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
        //File write


        //continue run
        boolean runTrue = true;

        //Ask

        while(runTrue == true) {
            System.out.println("Phonebook:");

            System.out.println("Please Enter Name:");
            String nameAsk = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please Enter Phone Number:");
            String numberAsk = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please Enter Addr:");
            String addrAsk = sc.nextLine();

            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Programs\\JavaProjects\\PhoneBook.txt");
                fw.write(nameAsk);
                fw.write(numberAsk);
                fw.write(addrAsk);

                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {


            }

            runTrue = true;
            if(nameAsk.equals("end")) {
                System.exit(0); 
                }
        }



        //Write to file



        //exit program

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FileWriter`'s constructor needs in your use case a second boolean parameter `true` so it does append text to the file instead of overwriting it.

Refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

Paco Abato's got you covered! Frankly this surely must have been asked before so you could have just searched it but since you have asked it here and shared your code I'd like to point out few other things. You don't need to open the file (new FileWriter part) in every iteration so you could separate that out like shown below. In this case you won't need the second argument to be true either and it'll work just fine while your program is running. When will u need the argument to be true? When your program exits and you run it again wanting to append in that same file.

Also I've appended new line character i.e "\n" at the end of every input as that'll allow you to differentiate b/w the name, phone number etc when reading from the file. Here "\n" acts as a delimiter. It could be any character of your choice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //File write

    //continue run
    boolean runTrue = true;

    //Ask
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Programs\\JavaProjects\\PhoneBook.txt", true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    if (fw != null) {
        while (runTrue) { //same as while(runTrue == true)
            System.out.println("Phonebook:");

            try {
                System.out.println("Please Enter Name:");
                String nameAsk = sc.nextLine() + "\n";

                if (nameAsk.equals("end\n")) {
                    fw.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                System.out.println("Please Enter Phone Number:");
                String numberAsk = sc.nextLine() + "\n";

                System.out.println("Please Enter Addr:");
                String addrAsk = sc.nextLine() + "\n";

                fw.write(nameAsk);
                fw.write(numberAsk);
                fw.write(addrAsk);

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```